# How to make CDHTMLDialog hidden until the page is loaded?

Tags: mfc, visual-c++

after calling the DoModal method the dialog will be shown immediately. but i need to make it invisible until the page is loaded. is that possible?

thanks
xx

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can make it hidden at start in

```
OnInitDialog()
   DWORD dwStyle = GetWindowLong(GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_STYLE);
   dwStyle -= WS_VISIBLE;
   SetWindowLong(GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_STYLE, dwStyle);
```

and then in `OnNavigateComplete` make it visible.
But if your page will load slow it will seems like your app hangup

Comment: thanks, it works. but i still can see the dialog shown on start and then disappeared. is it possible to make it invisible before it starts?

Comment: @x_x Do you use modal or modeless dialog?

Comment: i use a CDHTMLDialog as the main window. and i think it is probably modal since i did call the DoModal method

Answer (score 0):

```
//CYourDialog.cpp

void CYourDialog::OnWindowPosChanging(WINDOWPOS* lpwndpos)
{
     //allow to hide dialog at the startup of dialog,
     //delay the show of dialog until m_bVisible is set
     if(!m_bVisible)
     {
         lpwndpos->flags &= ~SWP_SHOWWINDOW;
     }

     CDialog::OnWindowPosChanging(lpwndpos);
}

//CYourHtmlView.cpp

void CYourHtmlView::OnDocumentComplete()
{
    m_pYourDlg->m_bVisible=TRUE;
    m_pYourDlg->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BOOL CYourDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    DWORD dwStyle = GetWindowLong(GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_STYLE);
    dwStyle -= WS_VISIBLE;
    SetWindowLong(GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_STYLE, dwStyle);
    Invalidate();
    CDHtmlDialog::OnInitDialog();
...
    Navigate(_T("www.google.com"));
    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

void CYourDialog::OnNavigateComplete(LPDISPATCH pDisp, LPCTSTR szUrl)
{   
    DWORD dwStyle = GetWindowLong(GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_STYLE);
    dwStyle += WS_VISIBLE;
    SetWindowLong(GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_STYLE, dwStyle);   
    Invalidate();
}
```